# ArcGIS JavaScript setRequestPreCallback is partially working?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.3

I have an api sitting in front of AGS that requires it's own authentication. I am using setRequestPreCallback as stated by the [ESRI docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html).

In the image below, you can see that the first 2 requests are returning 200. The first request is [CORS Preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) and the second request is the JS api getting the json info from the MapServer.

[image]

The second request uses the function I have set in setRequestPreCallback(...) to properly set a header value with the token. However, whenever an image is requested from the MapServer (via export), the function I have in setRequestPreCallback is not called and the token is not set, leaving me with a bunch of 401 Unauthorized requests.

I am running **AGS 10.3** with **JS API 3.14**

Here is the JS I am using:

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    'esri/request',
    'esri/config',
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, esriRequest, esriConfig, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {

  esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("my.url.com");

  var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
    center: [-118, 34.5],
    zoom: 8,
    basemap: "topo"
  });

  function myCallbackFunction(args) {

    if (args.url.indexOf('my.url.com') === -1) {
        return args;
    }

    args.headers = args.headers || {};
    args.headers.token = 'token';

    return args;
  }

  esriRequest.setRequestPreCallback(myCallbackFunction);

  map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://my.url.com/map/Assets_Service/MapServer"));
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also ags version

Comment: I updated the post to include the extra info.

Comment: Perhaps images are not requested via XHR? The simplest way to retrieve an image is to create an <img> element and set its src attribute. If this is the case then dojo might not even be involved

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a setRequestPreCallback, you can just append the token to the MapService, and the JSAPI will send it along:

`new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://my.url.com/map/Assets_Service/MapServer?token=" + token);`